# How To avoid duplicate PubSub delivery?

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

I'm working on an application where I will be getting 40 million records in a day so will the PubSub can handle it?. I have also seen that in some cases PubSub sends duplicate messages how can we avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

40 million records in a day (~460/s) is definition feasible for Pub/Sub, yes. The service is designed to scale horizontally with your load to tens of GB per second. Pub/Sub is an at-least-once delivery service by default, which means that duplicates are possible. There is an [exactly once feature](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/exactly-once-delivery) currently in public preview, which allows one to get stronger guarantees including:

1. Only one delivery of a message can be outstanding at a time.
2. A successful response to the Ack call means that the message is guaranteed not to be redelivered.

This does mean that if you don't ack a message before the deadline, the message will get redelivered, so it doesn't mean you avoid duplicates entirely. If you need exactly once processing, then [Dataflow can be a good choice](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/after-lambda-exactly-once-processing-in-google-cloud-dataflow-part-1).